# The lines are changed into green colour and not showing in the main document

Tags: error-writing

[image]

I have been writing my thesis, but suddenly the words are not showing in the main file. the Black colored words are showing but not the green colored ones.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. However, the problem is simple: when you write `58%` the `%` character starts a code comment, so the rest of the line is ignored by LaTeX. You need to escape the character if you want a percent sign in the output, i.e., `58\%`.

Comment: You have commented it out using %. If you want percentage, use \% .

Comment: For notation of quantities you should consider to use `siunitx` package and for example instead of wrong `50%` write `\qty{50}{\percent}` or shorter `\qty{50}{\%}`. Result is beside that will be correct, it will be nicer (consistent spacing between numbers and units, in your case percentages).